Google Form to Discord Webhook Not Working
I pulled this code from Github a few years ago, which is supposed to pull Google Form responses and post them to a Discord channel using a webhook. It was working flawlessly until a few months ago. Code below:
const POST_URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1237046117418401842/WFieSt7WaMHYWxmf58U6Cvui3t2LWGV1sZffw-XhCG9d5v5PB39ot7FGLvhKu5KO4VMB";

function onSubmit(e) {
    const response = e.response.getItemResponses();
    let items = [];

    for (const responseAnswer of response) {
        const question = responseAnswer.getItem().getTitle();
        const answer = responseAnswer.getResponse();
        let parts = []

        try {
            parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
        } catch (e) {
            parts = answer;
        }

        if (!answer) {
            continue;
        }

        for (const [index, part] of Object.entries(parts)) {
            if (index == 0) {
                items.push({
                    "name": question,
                    "value": part,
                    "inline": false
                });
            } else {
                items.push({
                    "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
                    "value": part,
                    "inline": false
                });
            }
        }
    }

    const options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            "contentType": "application/json",
        },
        "payload": JSON.stringify({
            "content": "‌",
            "embeds": [{
                "title": "GotFA Application",
                "color": 33023, // This is optional, you can look for decimal colour codes at https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/hexadecimal-decimal-color-converter.html
                "fields": items,
                "footer": {
                    "text": "Some footer here"
                },
                "timestamp": new Date().toISOString()
            }]
        })
    };

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
};


Upon submitting the Google Form, it does not post to the Discord webhook - instead, I get this error:
Exception: Request failed for https://discord.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: `{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}


I'm pretty sure that the reason that error occurs is because you sent an empty message. What that means is that this line:
"content":""

You have to put something in that content or else it will not work. Alternatively, just remove the content value which should work.

I have already tried both of these methods (1, removing the content line altogether, and 2, putting some kind of text in the quotation marks) and I'm still getting the same error unfortunately.

@Virgo Then the only other thing I can see that this code might be wrong is the content type header. Instead of "contentType" it should be "Content-Type".

Yeah, tried that too. I think that was one of the first suggestions I saw online, but that didn't work either unfortunately @SomeoneAndSomething
